# При использовании функции sendmail в php возникают проблемы с кодировкой

Tags: кодировка, php

При просмотре письма из браузера на gmail и [mail.ru](http://mail.ru) некорректно отображаются заголовки, а в outlook заголовки отображаются правильно, но текст письма нечитаем. Пробовал ставить charset как в примере, а также добавлять encoding-type в заголовок не помогло. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить.

```
// Для отправки e-mail в виде HTML устанавливаем необходимый mime-тип и кодировку
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset: cp-1251' . "\r\n";
// Откуда пришло
$headers .= 'From: Сайт' . "\r\n";

//Здесь укажите электронный адрес, куда будут уходить сообщения
$mailto = $email;
$subject = "Подтверждение регистарции на сайте";

$message = 'Для активации аккаунта пройдите по следующей ссылке <a href="http://***/registration/registration.php?
activation='.$uniq_id.'" target="_blank">http://***/registration/registration.php?activation='.$uniq_id.'</a>';
$message .= ' или скопируйте ссылку в окно ввода адреса браузера и нажмите enter.';
//Отправляем сообщение

//Отправляем сообщение
if(sendmail($mailto,$subject, $message ,$headers) !== FALSE) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

кривой пример. чарсет для заголовка не указывается, вот он криво и выводится.

вот к примеру...

http://www.internet-technologies.ru/articles/article_1361.html

Comment: я вообще давно не использую sendmail/mail, http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.factory.php

Answer (score 0):

Вы указали в поле Content-Type кодировку CP-1251, но это лишь означает, что у Вас тело письма будет в этой кодировке. Для темы письма необходимо указывать кодировку следующим образом:

```
$subject="=?windows-1251?B?".base64_encode("Подтверждение регистарции на сайте")."?=";
```